# Doesn't working gnome-control-center user-accounts

Tags: linux, user-accounts, arch-linux, gnome, user-profiles

As I have installed arch, I have installed gnome via pacman -S gnome gnome-extra. After installation I have rebooted. I have successfully logined as root. All seems to be okay, instead the fact that gnome-control-center user-accounts doesn't starts. I must notice the fact that all other options of gnome-control-center works very well!!! gnome-control-center user-accounts gives this information:

```
root:~ # gnome-control-center user-accounts

(gnome-control-center:20884): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:20884): AccountsService-CRITICAL **: act_user_set_language: assertion 'ACCOUNTS_IS_USER (user->accounts_proxy)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And with verbose mode:

```
    root:~ # gnome-control-center -v user-accounts
** (gnome-control-center:20924): DEBUG: Enabling debugging
** (gnome-control-center:20924): DEBUG: No extra argument
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG: gdk_pixbuf_from_pixdata() called on:
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Encoding raw
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Dimensions: 14 x 14
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Rowstride: 56, Length: 808
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Copy pixels == false
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG: gdk_pixbuf_from_pixdata() called on:
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Encoding raw
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Dimensions: 14 x 14
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Rowstride: 56, Length: 808
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Copy pixels == false
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG: gdk_pixbuf_from_pixdata() called on:
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Encoding raw
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Dimensions: 14 x 14
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Rowstride: 56, Length: 808
(gnome-control-center:20924): GdkPixbuf-DEBUG:     Copy pixels == false
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: calling 'ListCachedUsers'
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: Failed to identify the current session: No such device or address
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: seat unloaded, so trying to set loaded property
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Listing cached users, so not setting loaded property
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Listing cached users, so not setting loaded property
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: ListCachedUsers finished with empty list, maybe setting loaded property now
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Seat wouldn't load, so giving up on it and setting loaded property
(gnome-control-center:20924): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: Got 0 users

(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: trying to track new user with uid 0
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finding user with id 0 state 1
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finding user with id 0 state 2
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Looking for user with id 0 in accounts service

(gnome-control-center:20924): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion 'text != NULL' failed

(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-CRITICAL **: act_user_set_language: assertion 'ACCOUNTS_IS_USER (user->accounts_proxy)' failed
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: trying to track new user with uid 0
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finding user with id 0 state 1
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finding user with id 0 state 2
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Looking for user with id 0 in accounts service
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: unrefing manager owned by finished ListCachedUsers call
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Found object path of user with id 0: /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User0
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finding user with id 0 state 3
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: user with id 0 fetched
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finished handling request for user with id 0
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: unrefing manager owned by fetch user request
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: Found object path of user with id 0: /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User0
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finding user with id 0 state 3
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: user with id 0 fetched
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: finished handling request for user with id 0
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: unrefing manager owned by fetch user request
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: user root is now loaded
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: user root was not yet known, adding it
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: tracking user 'root'
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: loaded, so emitting user-added signal
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: no pending users, trying to set loaded property
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: already loaded, so not setting loaded property
(gnome-control-center:20924): AccountsService-DEBUG: ActUserManager: sending user-changed signal for user root
(gnome-control-center:20924): user-accounts-cc-panel-DEBUG: Got 0 users

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Worse yet, as I can't login with my account anymore. LightDM service won't start and GDM freezes upon login. I can only login as root through GDM.
Opening `gnome-control-center user-accounts` leads to the same error. This happened somewhere in the last 10 days, as I today rebooted the first time since 10 days...